# Нажатие на не интерактивный элемент через Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Я пишу парсер электронного дневника и столкнулся с проблемой. Иногда прикрепляют файл с домашним заданием. Вот в чём суть: хотелось бы скачать этот файл через Selenium, но чтобы это сделать, нужно нажать сначала на объект, который является не интерактивным, а потом уже появится ссылка на скачивание. Но как нажать на него, если объект не интерактивный?

[image: Вот сам код этого элемента]

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена. Помог xpath в поиске элемента

Comment: Пожалуйста, оставляйте немного более развернутые ответы. Дополнить ответ можно, нажав кнопку [edit].